# Anylogic inheritance and visible elements

Tags: anylogic

I'm building an agent that will be the father block of many others will inherit.
In this father block, I put 5 ports that I want to be part of the icon of the child agent, and when I import it with the "Extends other agents" in the Advanced tab menu, I can clearly see that those ports appear but they're not part of the icon.

[image]
[image]

As suspected in the main agent, when I import the one I'm building it appears only the red factory icon.
Is there a chance that importing the base agent that way I can see those ports in the icon, or should I drag and drop it in the "child"=

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - ports only show one level higher.

You will need to add ports on the child agent and then you can use them on main.